# Convert image from clipboard to base64 encoded data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, base64, clipboard

I want to be able to take a screenshot and then just simply paste it to the textarea field which would then turn the image into base64 encoded string. Then I could easily put it inside img elements src attribute.

Reason I want it this way is because I dont want to be forced to upload image itself somewhere nor be forced to save it, just copy and paste.

I have seen something like this at some site somewhere so I know its possible, I just dont know how its done and cant find the site anymore...

Comment: What do you have so far? How are you taking the screenshot?

Comment: Check out my answer or this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/zTAuR/). Paste the image, and you get alerted with the base64 data/png. :)

Comment: @sachleen, just a normal screenshot. Praveen already gave working answer :)